# How do I get my Facebook App approved if they need to test it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I created a Facebook connect login for my eCommerce website, which requires a Facebook app. The app is in review status (which means it does not work on the live site). But they require instructions on how to test my implementation.

Am I doing this the wrong way? Or should I create something like fb-test.html that shows how this works?

Thanks.

Comment: why is the app in review? are you using any extended permission that needs to review?

Comment: "Some Facebook integrations require approval before public usage. Before submitting your app for review, please consult our Platform Policy and Review Guidelines."